# Nested RecyclerView that changes position depending on selected category

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I'm having a hard time creating a nested recycler view that will allow the second one to appear depending on the "movie category" selected. This is what's supposed to happen in the app. Every time a user click a category, *recyclerview2* should appear on top of it. Has anybody ever done this before? How will I be able to implement it on this app? [2 RECYCLER VIEWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZkv9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you are trying to create a horizontal recycler view and on clicking its item it will show a vertical recycler view. Is that it? Please explain your question more clearly.

Comment: what I can infer from the photo you provided is that you can create tabs and just create different instances of a single tab fragment for different tabs.

Comment: @Arsh yes. basically, the first recyclerview should show the second recyclerview when clicked. It's like a header with a dropdown list. In this case, recyclerviews triggering the appearance of another recyclerview.

Comment: You just simply need to create a horizontal recycler view and when you click on any item of the view just assign a new list to the recycler view in onItemClick. You need to have a horizontal recycler view at the top and below it a vertical recycler view. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Arsh can this be achieved using the method you've shared? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pCi2yUqfWoQAcds3XQqRUxt1ORSxRIZE/view?usp=sharing) When the movie category is clicked, it needs to show a pop up and a list of movies.

Comment: so you want to implement this with your tabs at the bottom in an android app? You are showing an image of the desktop view. When you will create a tab in android it won't have this much space that your selected item joins with the list view below it or on top of it because the screen size is small.

Comment: _so you want to implement this with your tabs at the bottom in an android app?_ Yes. I'm developing an android TV app, that's why it has this much space.